# All files with same name into array (including sub-directories)

Tags: php

Please consider the following directory structure:

```
- artists
  - Ben-Major
    - Album 1
      - Song-1.mp3
      - album-art.jpg
    - Album 2
      - Song-1.mp3
      - album-art.jpg
```

As you can see, the directory for the `Ben-Major` artist contains two sub-directories (`Album 1` and `Album 2`), which in turn contain an MP3 file, and a JPG file. The names of the MP3 file is irrelevant, but the name of the JPG file, regardless of the sub-directory in which it appears will always be named `album-art.jpg`.

How can I pull in a random `album-art.jpg` file using the most efficient method in PHP for a given artist?

The problem is that certain Artist directories might not contain a file called `album-art.jpg` at all. I'd first thought of using `readdir()`, and then looping through the sub-directories and using `glob()` to find the file. However, I think that this will be mostly inefficient when we have several albums (it's possible certain artists will have 10+ albums).

Is there any way to use `glob()` in a recursive manner? Here's the psuedo-code of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
function getRandomAlbumArt($artist)
{
    $matchedFiles = getFilesInSubDirs('album-art.jpg');
    // ^^ This would loop over the subdirectories in the most efficient manner, returning
    //    an array of all matched files, including their directory path.

    $index = rand(0, count($matchedFiles) - 1);
    return $matchedFiles[$index];
    // ^^ return 1 of the matches at random
}
```

Comment: Can you use `glob("*/album-art.jpg")` to get all available files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `glob()` you can put the wildcard in a directory:

```
$matchedFiles = glob("artists/$artist/*/album-art.jpg");
```

Comment: While this is a way to find all files, question was not only to do that, but also to get random album cover for each artist.

Comment: That part is just as in your question, just select a random element of the array.

Comment: I disagree since OP wants to group them. However, that could be done via cycling through `$artist` in PHP-code. But then, you need to grap their list first - so, in any case, code above is not enough to resolve question issue.

Comment: I don't see anything about grouping in the question. The function takes the artist name as a parameter, and returns a single, randomly selected file as a result.

Comment: Thank you @Barmar. This one looks to be the most effective solution. Dealing with the matched files is no problem, I can figure that part out ;)

Answer (score 0):

If most of albums will contain `album-art.jpg`, and you already have paths to all albums. You could probably shuffle albums, pop first, check if it has file `album-art.jpg` by file_exists or similar. If not you pop next element in albums array...

This should be more efficient cause you probably get match in only few checkinig if file exists.

Although Barmar method is much more direct.